# Export a google sheet to CSV and email as attachment -> sends a CSV attachment but is populated with junk

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to export a specific sheet to CSV format and then email the csv file as an attachment in email. My code ends up emailing a CSV attachment okay, but the content of the csv attachment is bogus. I log the URL and then test this directly from the browser. It seems to find the correct named sheet. Is there a way to verify the result of `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`?  Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong here?

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var convertedSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dateToProcess);
  if (convertedSheet != null) {
  
    var sheetName = convertedSheet.getName();
    Logger.log("Sheet Name:", sheetName); // logs correct sheet name
    
    // this approach to constructing url is suggested in a similar post instead of using "getUrl()
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    url += '#gid=';
    url += convertedSheet.getSheetId();
    url += "/export?exportFormat=csv&format=csv";
    
    Logger.log("URL: ", url); //this brings up correct sheet when I paste the url in the browser. It does not trigger a  download of it in the browser - should it be?

    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    Logger.log(email); //correct

    var subject = "New Submission is Attached! ";
    var body = "You have a new submission!";

    var requestData = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+        ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
        
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData).getBlob();

    MailApp.sendEmail(email,
                      subject, 
                      body,
                      {
                          attachments: [{
                          fileName: sheetName + ".csv",
                          content: result.getBytes(),
                          mimeType: "text/csv"
                        }]
                      });
    
    }
```

In the CSV that is sent as an attachment, the cells are populated with what appears to be generated code (delimited by all the commas in the code).

Comment: Here is the basic format of the URL (minus id's and domains) ... h t t p s / / docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheet id>/edit?ouid=<sheet id>&urlBuilderDomain=<mydomain>.org#gid=<gid>/export?exportFormat=csv&format=csv"

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238548/blob-attachments-in-mailapp-sendemail

Comment: What about the other solutions?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491497

Comment: Ignore first comment above... After integrating suggested ways to format the url (not using 'getUrl', suggested in a previous post), I get this format which works from my browser:  h t t p s : //docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID#gid=SHEET_ID/export?exportFormat=csv&format=csv

Comment: But same issue with script. Not resolved.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience and the time difference in my area. I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. In this case, I think that you could resolve by your own skill. So I would like to delete my answer, because I don't want to confuse other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by adding calls to `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` between api calls that run asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Attempted in Jan 2022, including `flush()`, and it wasn't working for me.

**My solution was to simply change the URL format** to:

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SpreadSheetId + "/export?format=csv&gid=" + SheetId;
```

Where

```
SpeadSheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
SheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Name of your sheet").getSheetId();
```